# Resource request: Moyal $\star$-product based calculations

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, textbook-recommendation, online-resources, moyal-product

I already asked two questions about the Moyal $\star$-product [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306811/moyal-star-product-inverse) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306995/moyal-star-product-of-star-exponentials) but I think I'll have a lot more similar questions, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me with finding some good resources.

I'm interested in the properties of the $\star$-product based operations and objects, such as (obviously) multiplication, division, $\star$-exponents, $\star$-logarithms and $\star$-elementary functions in general. I'm also interested in $\star$-based calculus and objects such as $\star$-determinants. In other words, I'm looking for results, theorems and techniques related to anything that one would ordinarily find in analysis, but with $\star$-products instead of usual multiplication.

I found several papers/notes by *Akira Yoshioka* and they were useful, but I need something that could help me do the dirty work and make some calculations easier. There's obviously a ton of papers and books about the $\star$-product in the context of deformation quantization. That's all great and helpful, but it doesn't really  go beyond the abstract level into some of the calculations.

If you need me to clarify something, please do tell, I'm not exactly sure how exactly to say what I need, hopefully someone will understand.

Comment: The Moyal product is equivalent to a matrix product for matrices of infinite size, see [arXiv:math-ph/0001039](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0001039); so any resource on infinite-dimensional linear algebra should be effective.

Comment: I understand this is self-promotional, but we wrote our basic text-book [Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) for that very purpose, including the exercises... The idea is to maximize the number of exponential arguments and Bopp-shift away. Or else to use the Baker integral-shift representation and reduce integrals.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Nothing wrong with shameless self-promotion if it's helpful! :) Thanks!

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have asked the following MO question based on the comments. Could you take a look?  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459365/exact-calculations-with-moyal-product-by-bopp-shift

Comment: Answered it. You misquoted, misunderstood, and misapplied the Bopp Shift!